# Why won't my bootstrap modal pop up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a newsletter modal to popup as soon as the page is loaded but I'm having some trouble getting my modal to load when my screen loads. Can someone help me?

```
<!-- Introduction Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Subscribe our Newsletter</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Subscribe to our mailing list to get the latest updates straight in your inbox.</p>
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Popup -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @Breevie make sure that `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` loads before this script.

Comment: What are the console errors? Is `jQuery` loaded? Is `Bootstrap.js` or `modal.js` loaded ? Is the function `modal()` being recognized?

Answer (score 2):

your code working fine, you can try to check your jquery link and bootstrap link

```js
$(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Subscribe our Newsletter</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Subscribe to our mailing list to get the latest updates straight in your inbox.</p>
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```